# selecting un-id spans in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My markup is a div with 3 spans inside. How can I read the value of each span with jquery.

```
<div id="mod">
   <span>first span<span>
   <span>second span<span>
   <span>third span<span>
</div>

function getVars(){
  var span1 = ;
  var span2 = ;
  var span3 = ;
}
```

Comment: your question is a bit contradictory... do you actually wan't the text of all the spans, or just the first one?

Comment: @Pauli, I rephrased. I was experimenting with the first one, but will need to read each of them.

Comment: then gov's answer should do it

Comment: @Pauli, I think gov's answer gets only the first one.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/find/ *Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector.* it WILL return 0 or more elements that matches the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
$('#mod').find('span').text();
```

Comment: uhh $("#mod span").text(); is way better.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert($("#mod span:first").text());//First span child only
            alert($("#mod > span").text());// All span children
        });
```

Note: Make sure to close your span "".

Comment: For each span you can do it like this.$("#mod > span").text()). Just like the one I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      alert($("#mod span:eq(0)").html());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the span tags `<span> first </span>`  then it should work, all the answers

another variation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("#mod").children(":first").text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  span { color:#008; }
  span.sogreen { color:green; font-weight: bolder; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>John,</span>
    <span>Karl,</span>
    <span>Brandon</span>

  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Glen,</span>
    <span>Tane,</span>
    <span>Ralph</span>

  </div>
<script>
    $("div span:first-child")
        .css("text-decoration", "underline")
        .hover(function () {
              $(this).addClass("sogreen");
            }, function () {
              $(this).removeClass("sogreen");
            });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("div span:first-child") could be improved, it looks like he doesn't want all of the divs on the page, just the one named mod, and why would you ever use :first-child when you can write :eq(0), it's half as much text.